# Typescript create a view component which wraps HTMLElement for use with TweenMax

Tags: jquery, typescript, gsap

I'm trying to create my own basic view component class which wraps an HTMLElement or JQuery element so I can do something like.

```
var newObject:Component = new Component($('#someDiv'));

TweenMax.to(newObject, .5, {css:{left:10,...}});
```

Currently I need to return the div within my component for it to work with TweenMax. However I would like my component to be treated as the jquery or htmlelement so the above line of code would work.

I considered implementing the htmlElement interface but I couldn't find the actual interface to see all the function declarations I would need.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would use a subtly different way of doing this to break the leaking of jQuery outside of the component (i.e. if you switch from jQuery the consumers won't care).

```
class Component {
    public element: HTMLElement; 
    constructor(selector: string){
        this.element = $(selector).get(0); 
    }
}

var component = new Component('#myid');

TweenMax.to(component.element, .5, {css:{left:10}});
```

You could switch `this.element = $(selector).get(0);` to `this.element = document.querySelector(selector);` without breaking the code that uses the component class.

If `HTMLElement` was a class (rather than just an interface) you would be able to extend it to avoid the `component.element` part of this as you would be able to pass the specialised class. This isn't possible because in TypeScript `HTMLElement` is an interface-backed declaration.

If you just wanted to extend the definition of `HTMLElement` you could do that without a class:

```
interface HTMLElement {
    myAdditionalMethod() : string;
}

HTMLElement.prototype.myAdditionalMethod = function () {
    return 'Example';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class called Component you can do something like:

```
class Component{
    item:JQuery; 
    constructor(item:JQuery){
        this.item = item; 
    }
}

TweenMax.to(newObject.item, .5, {css:{left:10,...}});
```

Comment: Ah. yeah ok. I was trying to avoid having to do '.item' in the tweenmax call. I wanted to see if I could just feed the newObject through to the TweenMax call. Looks like it might not be as easy as I thought though.

Comment: Its because if you extend JQuery you really need to extend JQuery :)